# HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen10 server RHEL8

Tags: hard-drive, rhel8, hpe

I have two physical servers host RHEL8 lets name them (**server1**, **server2**).

**Server1** has 4 physical disks configured on RAID1. The size of disk1 and disk2 together equal 800GB, and disk3 and disk4 equal 2TB.

**Server2** has 2 physical disks configured on RAID1. The size of disk1 and disk2 together equal 800GB.

We need to remove two disks from **server1** (which is 200TB) and then put them in **server2**.

First, I did `lsblk` to see is the disks that will be removed empty or not, it display `sda,sdb,sdc,sde,sdf,sdg`. Why the total is 6 block devices? Where I have only 4 hard drives?

Anyways, I removed the two disks from **server1** and put them to **server2**, after that I go to HPE iLO to remove the array that made of removed disks from **server1** and to add new array to **server2** with the new hard dive. The configuration for RAID in HPE ILO for both servers looks good.

But when I saved the changes and reboot the system, the RHEL8 OS enter the emergency mode and there are a lot of logs related to the memory, something like  `mem [0009999999222222] reserved  mem [0333300000000] usable` and more more of logs that I can't understand.

Any one can guide me?

**Note:** All thing is physical no VMWare no virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nowhere enough information here to be able to help. What I can tell you from what you've described is: one, your primary system is not booting because of a disk issue, which in my limited experience quite often can be a broken RAID array; two, there is at least enough disk access to get you to at least an initial boot, so you may have a chance to repair that disk or RAID array and continue; and three, normally there should not be a lot of logs for memory, you may have to look at those closely to see if you're having ECC events and failing memory. (I'd actually suggest doing a memory test, if that's possible, before retrying the boot.)

Comment: I agree that there is not enough info here to tell what is going on.